# Grep Command Explanation required

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

Anybody explain me this grep command

```
grep "click" /opt/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2013-03-19.txt \
  | awk -F: '{if (($3 >= $hr) && ($4 >= $min)) print $0}' | wc -l
```

Comment: The `grep` filters out lines in the `.txt` file that contain the string `click`.  Is that really your question?

Answer (score 1):

`Grep` finds all lines that contain the the string of characters `click`. These lines are passed to `awk` which only prints the lines where the third fields is greater than or equal to to shell variable `$hr` and the fourth field is greater than or equal to the shell variable `$min` where the field separator is `:`*(although these shell variable won't be expanded due to the quoting)*. `wc -l` is then used to count the number of matches. Currently the pipeline won't display the number of lines expected due to shell variables not be expanded.

Your pipeline can be replaced *(and fixed)* with a simple `awk` script:

```bsh
$ hr=3
$ min=23
$ awk -F: -v h="$hr" -v m="$min" '/click/ && $3 >= h && $4 >= m{c++}END{print c}'
```

Comment: This is what i need
grep "click" localhost_access_log.2013-03-15.txt | awk '{if ($9 != 301) print $0}' | wc -l

grep "imp" localhost_access_log.2013-03-15.txt | awk '{if ($9 != 301) print $0}' | wc -l

If the number for entries is more than 10 in last 15 mins - email should be sent.

Answer (score 0):

There are three processes in the pipeline:

1. `grep` finds all lines containing the word "click" from the log file and passes them to `awk`.
2. `awk` breaks the line into fields using a `:` delimiter. It prints out the line if the 3rd field is greater than the specified `hr` and the 4th field is greater than the specified `mins`, although I don't see where you are setting the `$hr` and `$min`.
3. Finally, `wc` counts the lines printed by `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

`grep "click" /opt/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2013-03-19.txt` Search for the word `click` in the given file

`awk -F: '{if (($3 >= $hr) && ($4 >= $min)) print $0}'` Split each result from the grep using the seperator `:`. If the 3rd element is greater than `$hr` and the 4th element is greater than `$min`, print the 1st element.

`wc -l` Count all the printed elements.

So it seems like the command is counting how many lines in the log file have a timestamp greater than a specified hour and minute.